# Not able to install react-router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

> $ npm install react-router-dom@4.2.0 --save npm ERR! Unexpected end of
>   JSON input while parsing near '...TzfxLvz8PuwMlgQXO+TPr'
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
>   C:\Users\PACHU\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2018-06-14T05_43_34_319Z-debug.log

Comment: this can happen if you try to install older packages on higher version of node

Answer (score 4):

Try cleaning npm cache:

```
npm cache clean --force
```

After that you can try to install it again.

Answer (score 4):

Seems you have some broken dependencies or caching problem. So first, delete your node_module, then delete your `package-lock.json` and `yarn.lock`.

```
`rm -rf node_modules` 
`rm -ef package-lock.json`
`rm -rf yarn.lock`
```

You can clear npm cache using the following command

```
npm cache clean --force
npm cache verify
```

You can also clean yarn cache using

```
yarn cache clean
```

Then close your current terminal and open a new one. Finally, install your dependencies again using

`npm install react-router-dom --save` or `yarn add react-router-dom --save`

Comment: You forgot to mention to do `npm install` before (or after) running `npm install react-router-dom --save` to install all previously deleted dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

Install yarn and try:

```
yarn add react-router-dom --save
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add the version you want to install in package.json file then npm i to install

Answer (score 0):

Delete your npm module file
run this command npm cache clean --force
run this command npm i  react-router react-router-dom --save
everything should be ok .

Answer (score 0):

Delete your npm module file run this command npm cache clean --force run this command npm i react-router react-router-dom --save everything should be ok .

1. npm cache clean --force run
2. npm i react-router react-router-dom --save